# How to achieve the RBAC functionality in Azure kubernetes service?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

As of now what i did is that, Created kubernetes cluster and enabled RBAC in web UI while creating the cluster.Inside the cluster i created a namespace named as **development1**.Now i wanted to give access to a user on some kubernetes resources which are belongs to development1 namespace.For that i created a role and add a 
user for a particular namespace.

Here is my configuration files:

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hellonode
  namespace: development1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: samplenodeapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hellonode
        image: hellonode.azurecr.io/aks-deployments:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: webinar
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hellonode
  namespace: development1
  labels:
    app: samplenodeapp
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: samplenodeapp
```

role.yaml

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: development1
  name: developer-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets"]
  verbs: ["*"]
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods","pods/log","pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]
```

rolebinding.yaml

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer-rb
  namespace: development1
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: < Azure_AD_user_object-id>
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: developer-role
  apiGroup: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
```

Now i am trying to list the pods in deveploment1(namespace) using the command `kubectl get pods -n development --user=<Azure _AD_username>`. Instead of list the pods, getting the error like

> error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized).

Here my doubts are, Is there any necessity to create context for that namespace? and shall i add role in deployment.yaml and service.yaml?

I don't know something which i missed. Could any anybody suggest me, how can i give the permissions for a user on kubernetes resources in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to login to Azure Cli as that Azure AD user and pull the k8s config as that user (az aks get-credentials -n xxx -g xxx) and run `kubectl get po -n development`. I'm not sure what `--user` parameter means, but I would expect it to try and use that user from your kubeconfig (which you dont have). I cant find any references to allowing user impersonalisation using kubectl.

Dont forget to purge your kubeconfig before hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response 4c74356b41. As of my knowledge, we can list the pods using command `kubectl get pods -n development`. why because defaultly every namespace has cluster-admin access right.  Does AKS creates context for every namespace defaultly?

Comment: sorry, I dont understand the question. cluster admin is tied to cluster wide role, you dont need roles for every namespace for that. what you need to do - is use Azure AD use context to auth, and you are not doing that

Comment: In order to give the access to a user on particular namespace, we have to create context for that namespace along with user(User tied with context) and then, by using that context only we perform the different operation on kubernetes resources within the namespace in kubernetes on-premise. My question is, we are not at all using context here.

Comment: why not? you create the rolebinding and auth as that user

Comment: one more thing,shall i use `Azure AD use context` while performing the operations on that namespace? like `kubectl --context=AzureAD get pods`

Comment: no, look at the answer, kubeconfig that you pull as Azure AD user is already scoped to that user, you dont need anything additional. just `kubectl get po`

Comment: i created rolebinding as mentioned in my question. i am getting confused. can you please give an idea how can i list the pods for my namespace(development)?